# Can't get SQL results from my specific query (database design, or code issue)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I've been fighting with this query, and either I am missing something with my WHERE clause, or I just don't have this designed right.  I've tried some joins as well manipulation, but I only get halfway there.  So I thought I would put the question to the community.

Background.  Three tables. (I am simplifying to make the query easier).  One table is a list of users (people).  A user can belong to ZERO or more cities (city).

The tables of people and city are combined in a view listing all users and the cities they belong to.  NOTE a user is NOT REQUIRED to belong to a city to exist in this view or.  The view when combined has these fields:

```
vwListingUsersCity

userID
username
cityID
```

The sample view data would look like the following

```
1 person1   NULL
2 person2   1
2 person2   2
3 person3   1
4 person4   5
5 person5   7
6 person6   NULL
```

etc.. you get the idea

Now the issue is I am writing a query to another table called job.  A person can be assigned a job at a city, but they DO NOT have to be assigned a city to have a job.  CityID refers to a unique city (for simplicity, New York, Boston, etc.. ignore the idea that a city of the same name could be different places just for example).

The job schema is the following real basic:

```
JobTable
JobID (unique)
JobName

JobUserTable
UserJob_ID (PK identity)
CityID
UserID
JobID
DateEntered

etc...  a unique index of cityID, UserID is set. (you cant have more than one job at the same city for a user)

sample data of JobUserTable

1  NULL  1  1  sampledate
2  1     2  1  sampledate
3  4     3  2  sampledate
```

I am joining the vwListingUsersCity to the JobUserTable by UserID.  I want a listing of users who do not have a job assigned to them.  That's easy but because a user may belong to more than one city it prevents the second assignment from showing up (such as for example of person 2 has a job in city1 they wont show up in the query saying that they don't have a job at city2)

```
SELECT dbo.vwListingUsersCity.username, dbo.vw_ListUsersNoRole1.cityID
FROM            dbo.vwListingUsersCity LEFT OUTER JOIN
             dbo.JobUserTable ON dbo.vwListingUsersCity.ID =        dbo.JobUserTable.User_ID
WHERE        (dbo.JobUserTable.User_ID IS NULL)
```

So this is fine showing users who dont exist with a role assigned, but in the example above because user person2 who has a job already assigned at city1 wont show up in the query saying they have no role assigned at city2.

So my WHERE clause or something needs to be more robust.  The query needs to return users who don't have a job assigned to them for any city they do Or DO NOT belong to.

I am not sure this is possible the way I designed it, any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: MS-SQL Server used

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you are wanting a list of all users and cities where they do not have a job.  If this is correct I would start by doing a full join between cities and users to return a list of all users and all cities.  Then outer join to the jobs table ON (tempAll.UserID= jobs.UserID AND tempAll.CityID = jobs.CityID) to return the records that don't match.